# How to recreate float layout using css grid?

Tags: css, css-float, css-grid

I have a layout with an image on the left and some text content on the right.  It is laid out something like this:

```css
.left {
  max-width: calc(100% - 150px);
  float: left;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Sd8.png" /></div>
  <div class="right">Hello, I am Kitteh</div>
</div>
```

The basic idea is that the image can be **up to 300px** but must always leave at least 150px for the text content to the right.  The text content will fill up as much space as possible - which will always be at least 150px left by the image.

My goal is to recreate this using CSS grid, but I am confused by how to use `grid-template-columns` to get the same behaviour.  At the moment I have something like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto minmax(150px, auto);
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Sd8.png" /></div>
  <div class="right">Hello, I am Kitteh</div>
</div>
```

This respects the 150px minimum for the right hand column, but doesn't expand to meet the image.  How can I get the grid layout to behave the same as the floats in my first example?

Comment: instead of minmax(150px, auto); add minmax(150px, 1fr); Use fr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `minmax(150px, auto);` add `minmax(150px, 1fr)`

`fr` unit will take the space which is left.

fr unit is like persentages (%). But they do the hard work for us. For example if you want 4 columns same size you can do 25% 25% 25% 25%. Which will be similar to 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr.

But if you have `grid-gap: 20px` you will notice a scroll will appear if you use persentages. Fortunately fr unit will take care of this and no scroll will appear.

Also `grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr`, to converted to persentages will be
`grid-template-columns: 200px calc(100% - 200px)` so again fr unit is doing the hard work for us.

You can think the fr unit as free space since it is getting the available free space and doing some hard work for us.

Can get enough? [Check out awesome css grid video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQkVA6z3dFvbnBJetfYDAF3-cG_ubgdZR)

Hope this will help you.

[See it in action here](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/eywraw8t/360339/)

Comment: that appears to be working.  I've heard of `fr` but still unfamiliar with how it works - give me a moment to test this

Comment: Thanks - I was having trouble due to an unrelated css rule - but got it sorted.

Comment: thank you, I need to do more reading about this unit but yes that's helpful.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you see this awesome video series. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQkVA6z3dFvbnBJetfYDAF3-cG_ubgdZR