# Keep divs in a column next to float

Tags: html, css, css-float

Here's an example of some markup and css I'm working with:

```css
.left {
  max-width: calc(100% - 150px);
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.right {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .right.top {
    order: 1;
  }
  .right.bottom {
    order: 3;
  }
  .left {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Sd8.png" /></div>
  <div class="right top">Hello, I am Kitteh</div>
  <div class="right top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
  <div class="right bottom">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</div>
  <div class="right bottom">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? </div>
</div>
```

The basic idea is that the image can be **up to 400px** but must always leave at least 150px for the text content to the right.  The text content will fill up as much space as possible - which will always be at least 150px left by the image.  If you resize the snippet above you can see the image is responsive in size.

**The Problem:** I'd like all of the `.right` divs to stay in a column and not wrap once their height exceeds that of the `.left` div.

**Caveats:**

- Wrapping the `.right` divs is not an option because in this application they are re-arranged at various widths using flex `order` property. I've included a media query here to demonstrate.
- I've considered using javascript to set the height of the `.left` div equal to the sum of the `.right` divs but I really hate using javascript for layouts and I'd like to avoid this - especially since it would require recalculating the height if content should change or browser is resized.
- I tried using css grid as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52300624/how-to-recreate-float-layout-using-css-grid) but it ended up being a problem since this forces the first `.right` div to be of equal height to it's grid row, which is not what I want.
- Setting a left margin on the `.right` divs is also problematic since the image size is responsive and whatever margin I set ends up being wrong at certain screen widths.

Comment: Please explain the first caveat, or even better expand your code to include the reorder code.

Comment: will do - give me a moment

Comment: @Jasonbamber - updated.  you can see at small device width the elements switch positions using css flex and `order`

Comment: are the right element fixed number ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif - no, it can vary.  however, it would be easy enough for me to count them and write some dynamic inline css if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a visual trick. The idea is to use another element inside the right element to keep the content always on the right even if the element become full width, these elements will have similar size to the image but we add some negative margin to cover the padding/border of the right element and to create the illusion of non-wrapping elements. Then you make the image to be absolute position.

```css
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
}
.left {
  max-width: calc(100% - 150px);
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.right {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.right:before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  height: 112px;
  max-width: calc(100% - 100px); 
  width: 410px; 
  margin: -11px 10px -11px -11px;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Sd8.png" /></div>
  <div class="right">Hello, I am Kitteh</div>
  <div class="right">Meow, meow.</div>
  <div class="right">And furthermore... meow.</div>
  <div class="right">Another right</div>
  <div class="right">More right ...</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If the height is not fixed you can try using flexbox and the stretch alignment will make the pseudo element to have the same height as the content:

```css
.left {
  max-width: calc(100% - 150px);
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

img {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.right {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display:flex;
}

.right:before {
  content: "";
  max-width: calc(100% - 100px); 
  width: 410px; 
  flex-shrink:0;
  margin: -11px 10px -11px -11px;
  background: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Sd8.png" /></div>
  <div class="right">Hello, I am Kitteh Hello, I am Kitteh Hello, I am Kitteh Hello, I am Kitteh Hello, I am Kitteh Hello, I am Kitteh Hello, I am Kitteh</div>
  <div class="right">Meow, meow.</div>
  <div class="right">And furthermore... meow. And furthermore... meow. And furthermore... meow. And furthermore... meow. And furthermore... meow.</div>
  <div class="right">Another right</div>
  <div class="right">More right ...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is interesting and very weird.  what's the purpose of having border, margin, etc on the pseudo element?  and how are you calculating all those pixel values?

Comment: perhaps I should have made it clear that the height of my right hand divs is not set.  they are dynamic based on content so the height is unknown.  i only set a height in my question so they wouldn't collapse down to nothing... let me edit it now to make it more realistic

Comment: @billynoah to cover the style of the right element (background and border) .. negative margin is used to cover the padding+border, same thing for the height (padding + border) and width

Comment: I've tried your suggestion with my updated code but can't figure out how to make that work when the height of the right divs is not static or known.  Is it possible?  Sorry I did not make this clear until now.

Comment: i have to admit I have no idea what you've done there but it works.  gonna have to take time and dissect this.  thanks for your help

Comment: @billynoah it's easy ;) since the image is now absolute element it's out of the flow and I simply made the right element to be 2 column, an invisible column that will push the visible one to keep the content always on the right